# How to set text from user input in text android with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a JetPack Compose `TextField` which take user input, a button and a simple text.
What I wanna achieve is when user input something in the `TextField` and press the button the input should be displayed in the text, but text is unable to set the new value, it remains blank.

```
@Composable
 fun xyz(){
   Var textstate = remember {
     mutablestateof("")}
  
 Var otext: string? =""

Column(//styling....){
 Textfield(value= textstate.value,
   onValueachnaged= 
    {textstate.value=it}, label= 
     {Text(text=
       "Enter text")}

 Button(onCLick= {
  otext = textState.value
   }){}
   Text(text = otext.toString()
 }
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. I suggest you start with state in compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles. You need to use remembered mutable state for your text value too.

Comment: Kindly post the proper code. The code is syntactically wrong in many places. `Var`, `mutablestateof`, `Textfield`, `onValueachnaged`, `otext`. Update with correct spelling, case and format the code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write like this

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldDemo() {
    var text by remember{ mutableStateOf("")}
    var text2 by remember{ mutableStateOf("")}
    Column {
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {text = it}
        )
        Button(
            onClick = { text2 = text }
        ) {
            Text(text = "click")
        }
        Text(text = text2)
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesnt work .. i have allready tried this .. complied keep the state unchanged of the text in the Text...